# Question about variables with combination of extern and const

Tags: c++, constants, extern

I googled `const` + `extern` on the internet, but it seems there isn't really a good answer for my question.

`const` alone means internal linkage, but if I want to share a const variable among compilation units. Is `extern` the best choice?

Common solution would be:

```
//g.h
extern const int MAX;

// g.c
extern const int MAX = 3;
```

However, this solution has a drawback, like below:

```
// Say, I want to use this MAX in the same header file.
// g.h
extern const int MAX;
class AClass
{
public: 
    AClass (): i(MAX){}
private:
    int i;
};
```

Compiler will complain like:"error C2057: expected constant expression".

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: IIRC VS allows you to do `extern const int max = 3` in the header then `const int max;` in the source. This works at least for static members variables. BTW try removing the extern keyword in the source file since you are defining it there.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause multiple definitions?

Comment: @DaiHaoci : Why do you want external linkage in the first place? What advantage do you think it has?

Comment: To share it among compilation units.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : What's wrong with it having internal linkage, giving each translation unit its own copy, and letting the linker merge the duplicates?

Comment: What if the const variable is a huge database object?

Comment: @DaiHaoci : What if it is? There's still only one copy at runtime if your linker does its job correctly.

Comment: I didn't know that. Is this guaranteed by all linkers? Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : Merging duplicate objects is an optimization; the standard can't guarantee anything about what optimizations your toolset will perform. You'll have to consult your toolset's documentation for any further guarantees.

Comment: @ildjarn, thanks very much for your reply. It's very helpful. If the optimization is disabled, I still don't have a good solution to share `const` variables.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : Yes, you do -- Praetorian's answer describes exactly how. You just can't use variables defined that way as constant expressions, e.g. to specify the size of C-arrays. Again, there are two different issues here -- `const` variables and constant expressions; you need to understand the difference.

Comment: @ildjarn: I have modified my post. Please take a look again. `const` does imply internal linkage. Praetorian suggested to get rid of `const`, correct?

Comment: @DaiHaoci : Sorry, you're right, I didn't notice that Praetorian's answer used non-`const` variables. In any case, Praetorian's answer is still correct if the variable is `const`, i.e. if you make it `extern const int MAX;` in the header and `const int MAX = 10;` in the source file. Also, `const` implies internal linkage _by default_, but you can overrule that by declaring it as `extern`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to be able to use your constant at compile time (i.e. size an array by it, without using VLA) it has to be known at compile time, i.e. it cannot have external linkage.

However, you could just declare your constant in your header file, and make it available to anyone including it. Still, that won't have the exact same effect as an external linkage.

```
// a.h
const int MAX = 3;

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
int b[a];
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy solution for constant integers is to use enums:

```
// g.h
enum { MAX = 3; }
```

```
// g.c

#include "g.h"
static char buf[MAX];
```

You won't be able to take the address of `MAX`, but in turn you get this at zero memory cost.

Comment: If I want to define `buf` in the header file.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : You can do exactly that with this solution.

Comment: You are right. But, my question is more like how to share const variable among compilation units.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : You're failing to understand the distinction between `const` variables and constant expressions. Array initialization requires a constant expression; your variable being `const` doesn't magically make it a constant expression. See DeadMG's answer.

Comment: @Dai Haoci You do realize that if you declare `buf` in the header file you'll get multiple definition errors if you include that header in more than one compilation unit? You can declare it as a `static` to avoid this, but then every compilation unit would have its own copy of `buf`.

Comment: @Praetorian, that's true. I modified my post. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

```
extern const int MAX;
int i[MAX];
```

Can't be done. You could do something like

```
const int MAX = ReadAnIntegerFromTheConsole();
```

Perfectly valid and legal, but whoopsies- not a constant expression.

Comment: But, why it is allowed to combine extern and const?

Comment: @DaiHaoci : The former is a linkage specifier, the latter is a type decorator. `const` just happens to imply internal linkage (`static`) _by default_; that doesn't mean you can't overrule that default.

Comment: @ildjarn: its character changed after overrule the default. If it is not `extern`, I could declare `int i[MAX]`.

Comment: @DaiHaoci : Yes, once again, you're confusing `const` variables and constant expressions. **Please** read about the difference between these two concepts before continuing with this question.

Answer (score 2):

> `const` alone means internal linkage

This is not correct, `static` indicates internal linkage, `const` just says the object cannot mutate. Try declaring a variable as

```
extern static int foo;
```

Your compiler will complain about conflicting linkage. To share a `const` between translation units do exactly what you've suggested.

In the header

```
extern const int MAX;
```

In the source file

```
const int MAX = 10; // note you can omit the extern here
```

Comment: Your answer would make more sense if you declared/defined `MAX` as `const`. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that may solve your issue.  In summary, define the array size as a constant in a header file.  In another header file declare the array as `extern`.  In the example below I reference the array as `extern` without using an include file for the array.

**array_size.hpp**

```
const unsigned int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 16;
```

**array.cpp**

```
#include "array_size.hpp"
int array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "array_size.hpp"

// Reference the array from array.cpp
extern int array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
  array[1] = 7;
  return 0;
}
```

The *array_size.hpp* file defines the size, the identifier can be used in other translation units by including the header.

I compiled on Cygwin using:

```
g++ -I. -o array.exe main.cpp array.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a #define?

```
#define MAX 3
```